# Differentiation in fields with norm or metric

Tags: derivatives, reference-request

We start learning about derivatives in the real numbers setting.
And we know that the reals are the only complete ordered field possible.
But what happens if we relax the "order" property?
The definition f'(x) = lim (f(x+h) - f(x))/h, h -> 0, still holds,
if we introduce a metric (or norm), so that the limit makes sense.
So what is the general theory for this setting, i.e.,
calculus in metric, or normed, fields?
I have seen various articles even for topological fields,
but is there a good textbook survey of the various approaches and applications?
And is this topic an active area of current research?

Comment: I once asked a similar question with some good answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3845538/can-we-define-a-derivative-on-the-p-adic-numbers . At least on the complex numbers, this works flawlessly, giving us the field of complex analysis. But it works on other fields as well.